# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'verify_bool' property

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, soap-client, lets-encrypt

After updating my SSL certificate **Letsencrypt** on server (Linux Ubuntu), I am getting error "**SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'verify_bool' property**" when sending SOAP request. I am using **SoapClient.php** in **Laravel** application. Before updating the certificate it worked fine.
My code is here:

```
$soap_client = new \SoapClient("https://.....?WSDL", array(
                'local_cert' => app_path('Services/my.pem'),
                'passphrase' => 'mypasphrase')
        );

        $auth = $soap_client->AuthenticateUser(array(
            'aName' => '777.SSL.888',
            'aPassword' => 'password'
        ));

        $session_id = $auth->AuthenticateUserResult->SessionID;

    $data = $soap_client->getClientsByKeyFields(array(
            'aSessionID' => $session_id,
                           'aClient' => array(
                'ID' => 0,
                'Natural_Person_Bool' => 1,
                'Class_ID' => 10,
                'Sex_ID' => 0,
                'SETTLEMENT_ID' => 0,
                'DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID' => 0,
                'ACTIVITY_KIND_ID' => 0,
                'RESIDENT_BOOL' => 1,
                'ECONOMICS_SECTOR_ID' => 0,
                'COUNTRY_ID' => 0,
                'IIN' => $iin)
        ));
```

Comment: Hi! Rather than editing the title of your post to say it's solved, the convention here is that if you think the answer might be useful to future readers, you can [answer the question yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer); or if not, you can [delete the question completely](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Comment: Thank you. Added the comment below. For someone new in php  might be useful)

Comment: How did you get class id, if you don't have client id?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was simple. I just needed to add "verify_bool" item to the array  for 'aClient' in "getClientsByKeyFields()" function with default value, so my edited code for $data is

```
$data = $soap_client->getClientsByKeyFields(array(
        'aSessionID' => $session_id,
        'aClient' => array(
            'ID' => 0,
            'Natural_Person_Bool' => 1,
            'Class_ID' => 10,
            'Sex_ID' => 0,
            'SETTLEMENT_ID' => 0,
            'DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID' => 0,
            'ACTIVITY_KIND_ID' => 0,
            'RESIDENT_BOOL' => 1,
            'ECONOMICS_SECTOR_ID' => 0,
            'COUNTRY_ID' => 0,
            'IIN' => $iin,
            'verify_bool' => 1)
    ));
```